# конвертировать html div блок в pdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, jquery

На сайте есть блок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать возможность чтобы можно было скачивать этот div блок с картинками в pdf формат при нажатие на кнопку.
Буду рад за помощь.

Comment: Могу предложить https://packagist.org/packages/tecnickcom/tcpdf
популярный пакет для генерации pdf и баркодов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую рассмотреть вариант генерации div в изображение с помощью [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), а затем сгенерировать PDF c изображением через [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf).